# how to assign encryption property to jsPDF object

Tags: encryption, pdf-generation, jspdf, pdfkit

I am using jsPDF to create a pdf. I have successfully created the pdf file. but I want to encrypt my pdf file and allow accessibility like "print, modify, copy". after adding an encryption property to the following code it will not encrypt my file.

here is the code. so what should I have to do to encrypt the pdf file?

```
  <code>

 doc = new jsPDF({
 unit: 'pt', // set the unit of measurement to px
 format: 'a1', // set your paper size format
 userUnit:72, // set the DPI you desire. We used 72 because thats 
 the default DPI used in browsers.
  encryption: {
        userPassword:"1234sds@esdsdsds#22s5",
        ownerPassword:"797233232#2ewwe24",
       userPermissions:["print","copy"]
    } 
   });  //
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you don't have an answer yet. I think you have already found an answer. However, I would like to answer the empty question. You already create a document with the passwords.

If you do `doc.save('document.pdf')` it should ask for a password when you open it. The owner password should give you all permissions. The user password should give you only the set permissions.

If you try to save the password with `doc.output()`  as with
`window.open(URL.createObjectURL(doc.output('blob')))`  will not work. I think this does not work in any print preview but only when downloading the PDF file directly.